# how to bind ngModel in ngFor using angular5

Tags: angular

Cananyone please help. I am using ngFor to iterate through an array and I need to bind the headings to ngModel. How many headings i have entered, that all headings i tested by giving an alert in ts file. It gives an empty alert.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzcy61?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you will need to update your stackblitz link to show what you code instead the preview

Comment: I apologize to all. now i update the link. please help.

Comment: your component code does not make any sense. you are pushing integers into an array and then you try to set some property on that integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the input value in arrayOfObj;

Just click the 'Add new heading button" and enter whatever you want in the `<input>` block; replace your code in stackblitz with the following HTML and TS.

**app.component.html**

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="head1" placeholder="enter text">
<ng-template #temp>
  <div *ngFor="let a of arrayOfObj">
    <input class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter heading..." [(ngModel)]="a.head2">
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="btn-div">
        <div class="ss" (click)="onAddRow()" *ngIf="tmpo!=2;else tempo">Add new heading {{a.count}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="btn-div">
    <div class="ss" (click)="onAddRow()" *ngIf="tmpo!=1;else temp">Add new heading</div>

    <input type="button" class="ss" value="submit" (click)="submit()">
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormArray, NgForm } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  head1: string = '';
  head2: string = '';
  tmpo;
  count = 0;
  arrayOfObj: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.arrayOfObj = [];
  }

  onAddRow() {
    this.tmpo = 1;
    this.count++;
    this.arrayOfObj.push({ "count": this.count, "head2": "" });
  }

  onAddRow1() {
    // this.tmpo=2;
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.arrayOfObj);
    for (var i=0; i<this.arrayOfObj.length; i++){
      alert(this.arrayOfObj[i].head2);
    }
    //alert(this.head1)
    //alert(this.head2)
  }

}
```

Comment: It gives alert of head1, but not give by adding new headings like heading2,heading3....

Comment: check the console ... we are printing the values in console.log

Comment: @PRUDHVIRAJ, check now, added loop to alert out the head2 values which you wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood on how the binding works and about how you bind it.

Even structurally, you are not doing it right in terms of HTML, or maybe I just don't understand what are you trying to do.

For your case, at the moment, the array is just a normal array, you need to turn it into array of object, such as:

```
export class AppComponent {
  head1: string = '';
  head2: string = '';
  tmpo;
  count = 0;
  arrayOfObj: {head: string; position: number}[] = [];

onAddRow(){
this.tmpo=1;
this.count ++;
this.arrayOfObj.push({head: '', position: this.count});
}
```

Then your HTML can be:

```
<ng-template #temp>
  {{arrayOfObj|json}}
  <div *ngFor="let a of arrayOfObj; let i = index">
      <input class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter text..." [(ngModel)]="arrayOfObj[i].head"> 
        <br>
        <br>   

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-div">
              <div class="ss" (click)="onAddRow()" *ngIf="tmpo!=2;else tempo">Add new heading {{a.position}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

ngModel does work in for loop, but you need to reference it by the array via index.